# Workflow for an Angular form that also includes a file upload - what to do in case of errors (MEAN stack)

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular-reactive-forms, mean-stack, angular-forms

I have an account creation form with an optional profile picture file upload. If the user submits (after validation), I need to store the profile picture (eventually S3 or another cloud service) and save the form data. However, if there is a problem with the file upload, then the account shouldn't be created and data shouldn't be stored in the database (including the file reference as the file isn't saved). At the same time, if there is an error saving to the database, I don't want to upload & store the image because it isn't associated with any account since the account wasn't saved. How is this typically handled? Right now, I have two services, one that uploads a file, and another that stores the data in mongodb, but both operate independently of one another.

This is what I was attempting to do, but realized isn't going to work the way I need it to when there are errors from either service.

**file-upload.service.ts**

```
uploadFile(file: File) {
    return this.http.post(FILE_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, file);
}
```

**create-account.service.ts**

```
createAccountService(account: any) {
    return this.http.post(CREATE_ACCCOUNT_ENDPOINT, account);
}
```

**registration.component.ts**

```
submitForm() {
    const createAccountService = this.authServices.createAccountService(this.registrationForm.value)
  
    let services = [createAccountService];
    if (this.profilePicFile) {
      const uploadFileService = this.utilServices.uploadFile(this.profilePicFile);
      services.push(uploadFileService);
    }
    return forkJoin(services).subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        // Both are successful, now let's validate our email and log in.
      },
      error: (e) => {
        // At least one is unsuccessful, however we don't want to the other to have occurred due to one being unsuccessful, but at this point it is too late.
      }
    });
  }
```

I know this is a pretty common workflow, but this is my first time requiring both at once and I know there has to be a more intelligent way to do it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems like you'd want to use one endpoint.  Have you considered just sending formData object to a single endpoint.  (Better way to go anyway so it can be streamed...)  Then you can let the back-end handle the account creation logic and return any validation errors or success.

Comment: That's fair, however I would still run into the same problem, wouldn't I? On the backend I either upload the file to S3 (or whatever) then attempt to save the user, or I save the user then upload the file. If one of those two things fail after the other one succeeds then there will either be a picture not connected to a user or a user in the database with a reference to an image that isn't there. No?

Comment: You'd create the record first, get the primary key to use to use as part the image file's name (you want full control over that filename... the filename passed to server is untrusted user input)  If that fails, return error stating so... the file will, at this point, be in a temporary folder.  (Leave it alone if writing the record fails, the server will clean it up.)  If record write successful, copy that over to it's permanent directory and if that step fails, remove the record and return error.  Else return success.